# Is ipa file enough for iphone app ad-hoc distribution?

Tags: iphone, ad-hoc-distribution

I followed the instructions to generate an ad-hoc distribution file (.ipa) for my app, now I have couple questions 
1. do I still need to zip it up with mobileprovision file to give to my tester?
2. would it be possible for other unauthorized people to deploy on to their iphone and run the app? I believe the device UUID should prevent that, but just want to make sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You don't need to additionally provide the provisioning profile. Xcode will put it into the .ipa file, if you generated the .ipa with the Organizer.
2. By default it will not be possible. BUT if someone else has a jailbroken device, it is possible to run the app. Also if the other person has a iOS developer certificate, he can resign it with his own certificate and run the app. But other than that, the app will not run if the device is not part of the provisioning profile.

Answer (score 1):

What VeryVito said. Would also like to add: have you seen [Testflight](https://testflightapp.com/)? Makes getting your app to testers a lot easier. And Testflight has a (optional) SDK so you can add various things to your app, like tracking waypoints, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You will need the mobileprovision file as well. And no, others not included in the profile will not be able to run the app.